# Tab key not working in Emacs ruby-mode

Tags: ruby, emacs, emacs24

Having an issue with Emacs 24.2.50.1 running on Debian. In ruby-mode whenever I hit tab key to edit indentation, I receive the error: "Wrong-type-argument: number-or-marker-p, nil"

Further inspection reveals this about the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
ruby-calculate-indent()
ruby-indent-line()
indent-for-tab-command(nil)
call-interactively(indent-for-tab-command nil nil)
```

Note that tab key works as it should outside of ruby-mode (works fine in python-mode, etc), so I think it must be a bug within ruby-mode for indenting, but any help in diagnosing and fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: 24.2.50.1 is a development version, so please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Stefan, was suspecting that this was related to the issue, will do.

Comment: Is it working? Have you just given up? This question is a month old, and I don't see any new bug reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Emacs 24.2. `ruby-indent-level` was set to 0 by `python-mode`.

I made the following changes in python-model.el:

```
(defvar ruby-indent-level nil)
(defvar nxml-child-indent nil)
```

to

```
(defvar ruby-indent-level 2)
(defvar nxml-child-indent 2)
```

then `M-x byte-compile-file`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and replaced built-in ruby-mode with [Enhanced Ruby Mode](https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode). You can try it if you're using Ruby 1.9.2 or later.

Comment: unfortunately `enh-ruby-mode` seems to have the same problem…